# Single match query request vs Multiple match query request in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Which is better between doing a single match query request vs multiple match query requests in Neo4j? (Note: only read (MATCH/OPTIONAL MATCH) cypher here, no write operation cypher is concerned).

In my case, using a single match query request will make the cypher end up with many `WITH` statements and the cypher will look big, I'm worry about the cypher readibility.

On other side, by using multiple match query requests, I worry about the performance because there would be multiple database hits.

So anyone can give me a thought about this? If I should after performance, should I go with single query request approach?

FYI, I'm using Neo4j v2.2.

**UPDATE:**

An example of a single match query:

```
MATCH (a:A {id: {id} }), (b:B {id: {id2} })

WITH a, b

MATCH (b)-[:R1]->(x:X)
OPTIONAL MATCH (y:Y)-[:R2]->(x)

WITH a, b, COUNT(y) as c

OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[r3:R3]->(b)

WITH a, b, c, COUNT(r3) > 0 AS d;

... // another MATCH/OPTIONAL MATCH & WITH statements

RETURN a, b, c, d, ...;
```

If using multiple query request:

```
// Query 1
MATCH (a:A {id: {id} }), (b:B {id: {id2} })
RETURN a, b;

// Query 2
MATCH (b:B {id: {id}})-[:R1]->(x:X)
OPTIONAL MATCH (y:Y)-[:R2]->(x)
RETURN COUNT(y);

// Query 3
MATCH (a:A {id: {id}})-[r3:R3]->(b:B {id: {id2}})
RETURN COUNT(r3) > 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Smaller match statements are easier to plan and execute.
Also easier to cache the compiled plans as they are repeatedly used (with parameters).
You can also run them concurrently. And you can send multiple of them in the same http request if need be.

So you can do an initial query for retrieving a larger set of data and then page that set and send smaller concurrent queries for reading more of each chunk (or writing data for each chunk).

On the downside you have to re-lookup data that you already had in your hand and you have additional network and serialization effort.

Mostly it depends on your use-case and SLAs (throughput and latency)

Comment: With single query request (assumed using parameters too), only one database hit is needed to get the result, so logically it will be faster than concurrently executed multiple query requests?

Answer (score 1):

You can always use newlines (say, after commas) and indentation to make a long `MATCH` statement readable.

On the other hand, breaking a long `MATCH` statement into multiple statements does not necessarily change the neo4j behavior or your performance (since the Cypher mechanism does a good job of optimizing). To be sure, you can use [PROFILE or EXPLAIN](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.4/how-do-i-profile-a-query.html) to compare the behavior of alternate versions of your query.

But there is a big caveat. A single `MATCH` statement (that involves relationships) will automatically filter out duplicate relationships; this is normally what you want. If you break that up into multiple `MATCH` statements such that not all relationships are matched in the same statement, then you will lose that filtering. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31001752/neo4j-cypher-match-command-concatenation/31009701#31009701) for more info.